# How to disable the collapsing of an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to implement a `ExpandableListView` which should be expandable only after all the values have been set up within the adapter. Also I would like to be able to disable the collapsing of the expander.

Can I achieve this within an Android XML Layout?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can define a `OnGroupClickListener` which returns `true`, like so:

```
expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
    return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way that I know of this to be done from xml.

You could add an `OnGroupClickListener` to the `ExpandableListView`, and consume its event if the group is already expanded:

```
myExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v, int groupPosition, long id)
    {
        return parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But i have made some changes to it and it worked for not collepse the list

Comment: Thank you very much. But i have made some changes to it and it worked for not collepse the listid.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
   
   public void onGroupCollapse(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ExpandableListView expand=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    expand.expandGroup(id);
   }
  });

Comment: hank you very much. But i have made some changes to it and it worked for not collepse the listid.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() { public void onGroupCollapse(int id) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub ExpandableListView expand=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1); expand.expandGroup(id); } });

Comment: You should post your solution here, and you'll be able to accept it in 48 hours. You should do that, so this question to be closed. Please note though, that with your solution the list will collapse and right after that expand each group, so might be a lot waste. By consuming the click event you prevent the list from collapsing.

Comment: I know that i am preventing the click event. But my requirement is in such a way. I have to expand my expandable list view all the time. SO i have the Prevent the Collapse event. Can you guide in expanding the ExpandableListview at the start itself.

Comment: You are not preventing, neither consuming the click event. You let it (and so the collapse to) happen, and correct the damage: expand the list again.