# How to make an ExpandableListView in Android always show child items

Tags: android

I want to make an `ExpandableListView` which should always be showing its children elements 
even after clicking the header, and it should not collapse. How could I implement this concept?

Comment: Why are you using `ExpandableListView` in this case? Just use a regular `ListView`, with different row layouts for the "children" to suggest that they are children (e.g., contents indented).

Comment: for(int i=0;i<listAdapter.getGroupCount();i++){
         listView.expandGroup(i);
        }

Comment: and in oncreatelistView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      listView.expandGroup(groupPosition); 
   }
  });

Answer (score 1):

you can expand all groups one by one as below as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081007/expandablelistview-group-view-expand-default) post

```
ExpandableListView explst;

explst.expandGroup(0);
explst.expandGroup(1);
```

for disabling collapse you can define a OnGroupClickListener which returns true, like so: (as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844980/how-to-disable-the-collapsing-of-an-expandablelistview) post)

```
explst.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
    return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
  }
});
```